# git tag on parent repo doesn't show corresponding tagged version of submodules

Tags: git, tags, git-submodules

I have a parent repo and have a git submodule inside this repo from another repository. This submodule was created sometime back and has its old commit reference. It shows up in the parent repository as "**submodule-name @ 47b883bbcf4**"

Later post a release, I tagged this parent repository to 1.2.0 and also tagged the submodule (in its original repository) to 1.1.0.   But when I access the 1.2.0 tag  in parent repository and it is still pointing to the **47b883bbcf4** commit. How do I enforce it to point to 1.1.0 tag in the submodule's repository?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. A tag is a name for a single Git commit hash. You set a tag in a repository and it points to that commit hash. If the repository is a superproject (has a submodule), the mechanism the repository uses to check out one specific submodule commit hash is the same as it always is, which does not use tags at all.

Answer (score 0):

A [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) would always reference a Git SHA1 in its [gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) (special entry in its index).

Even when a submodule [follows a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), it references a SHA1.

You can add a tag to a submodule repo and push that tag, but a later clone of the parent repo will checkout the submodule repo to the SHA1 of its git entry anyway, tag or not.